# SQLite3, FTS3 and stop-words

Tags: sqlite, stop-words

How do you prevent SQLite3 from not indexing certain key words, or "stop-words", during the build of a virtual FTS3 table?

Examples I'd like to not index include "is", "the", "a" etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no built in tokenizer that handles stop words, so you will either need to implement your own tokenizer in C and filter out the stop words from the list manually, insert pre-tokenized/pre-filtered text into the relevant FTS table column or use a somewhat convoluted scheme where you insert the text into the FTS column, fetch it back after its been tokenized, filter it and then update the column value.